# Разница между вложенным оператором if и логическими конструкциями

Tags: python, if

Вот есть ли например отличие между

```py
if condition1 and condition2:
```

и

```py
if condition1:
    if condition2:
```

Например, задачу определить делится ли число на 3 и/или на 5 можно решить:

```py
num = 10
if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
    print('Число делится на 3 и на 5')
elif num % 3 != 0 and num % 5 != 0:
    print('Число не делится на 3 и на 5')
elif num % 3 != 0 and num % 5 == 0:
    print('Число не делится на 3 но делится на 5')
else:
    print('Число делится на 3 и не делится на 5')
```

Или же:

```
if num % 3 == 0:
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print('Число делится на 3 и на 5')
    else:
        print('Число делится на 3, но не на 5')
else:
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print('Число делится на 5, но не на 3')
    else:
        print('Число не делиться ни на 5 ни на 3')
```

В каких ситуациях следует использовать тот или иной подход и есть ли какая-то разница между этими вариантами?

Comment: Разницы нет, если вы не забудете корректно обработать все возможные варианты ветвления.

Comment: @CrazyElf, у меня получается, что по скорости разница существенная.

Comment: @Сергей есть объективные результаты тестов?

Comment: @Dmitry, да. Вместо `print` автора сделал присваивание, чтобы буфер не забивался, и запустил оба варианта автора в цикле на 1 000 000 раз. Первый случай раза в два длиннее в среднем отрабатывает (например, 0.25 сек против 0.12 сек).

Comment: @Сергей похоже на правду, тогда запись в словарь по таким тестам будет еще дольше. Вопрос, насколько они отражают действительность в реальной жизни

Comment: @Dmitry, моя основная идея в том, что нет однозначного ответа. Вопрос в приоритетах, и надо думать, часто ли будет тот или иной вариант повторяться. Желательно знать алгоритмику ещё, конечно.

Comment: @Сергей надо PEP поковырять на эту тему)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136217/discussion-between--and-dmitry).

Comment: Разницы нет, но лучше по возможности не использовать вложенные `if`.

Answer (score 5):

В Вашем варианте можно сделать и так, и так. Тут вопрос больше в читаемости кода. При сложных ветвлениях можно упустить какой-то из вариантов.

Можно, к примеру, организовывать кейсы с ответами через словари. Так код, на мой взгляд, будет выглядеть немного более читаемым.

```
num = 3
res = {(num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0): 'Число делится на 3 и на 5',
       (num % 3 != 0 and num % 5 != 0): 'Число не делится на 3 и на 5',
       (num % 3 != 0 and num % 5 == 0): 'Число не делится на 3 но делится на 5',
       (num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 != 0): 'Число делится на 3 и не делится на 5'}[True]
print(res)
```

Comment: Andy, +1 - тоже вариант "питоничный", и фразы уцелели:-) Особо `[True]` после словаря мне понравилось - что это за синтаксис?

Comment: Обычный словарь с двумя ключами True и False

Answer (score 4):

Тут условия особо ничего не меняют, код сильно лучше не становится, в обоих случаях много однотипных повторяющихся кусков. Как вариант можно сделать так:

```
num = int(input("Введите число:"))

x, y = 3, 5
div_by_x = num % x == 0
div_by_y = num % y == 0

if div_by_x and div_by_y:
    print(f'Число делится на {x} и на {y}')
elif not div_by_x and not div_by_y:
    print(f'Число не делиться ни на {x}, ни на {y}')
else:
    if div_by_y:
        x, y = y, x
    
    print(f'Число делится на {x}, но не на {y}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Между двумя верхними вариантами нет логической разницы. Но есть разница с точки зрения "питоничности" - в одну строку правильнее, так как яснее.

Выбирая между вашими вариантами решения задачи для ясности я бы выбрал верхний вариант.

Но надо учесть, что нижний вариант работать будет значительно быстрее, поэтому при использовании в варианте с длительными вычислениями выбрать надо его.

Я бы решал её короче для той же "питоничности", фразы чуть длиннее будут, правда:-)
Можно, конечно, поперебирать фразы, чтобы ближе к образцу были.

```
    num = 10
    v3 = 'не ' if num % 3 else ''
    v5 = 'не ' if num % 5 else ''
    print ('Число '+ v3 + 'делится на 3 и ' + v5 + 'делится на 5')
```

Answer (score 3):

Предложу свой вариант со словарем. Почему мне не нравится вариант ТС: в каждой ветке `if` вы делаете вычисления. Мое желание вычислять только один раз и хранить готовые результаты

```py
num = 10 
dict_ = {
    3: "не делится на 3" if num % 3 else "делится на 3",
    5: "не делится на 5" if num % 5 else "делится на 5",
}
print(f"Число {dict_[3]} и {dict_[5]}")
```

Играться можно долго и по разному, вплоть до совсем фантастических вариантов. Но по большей части нет разницы сколько много и как глубоко уходят ветвления if. Основное, на мой взгляд, - это читаемость. Часто вижу, как возможность записать в одну строку всю логику, убивает понимаемость/читаемость кода.

**UPD**

После некоторых экспериментов со скоростью выполнения могу резюмировать, что сама конструкция `if` при большом масштабировании процесса (в 10^6 и 10^9 раз) на скорость почти не влияет. Выяснил, что данное решение проигрывает в скорости только по причине использования форматирования через `f-строку`. Поэтому, с простыми арифметическими операциями, как у вас, нет смысла отдавать предпочтение той или иной конструкции, поскольку разница во времени мизерна. Остаемся в понятиях читаемости и удобства использования

Comment: Как писал выше, ещё скорость может быть важна. Тут выбирать надо тогда между ней и читаемостью.

Comment: Ваш вариант немного дольше самого длинного из вариантов автора, кстати

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант будет быстрее, но так как (просто несоизмеримо) большую часть времени будет занимать ввод/вывод, это не так уж важно в этой задаче. Важнее читабельность кода.
И здесь плюсы и минусы есть у обоих вариантов. Сильно вложенные лесенки обычно читаются сложнее, но квадратный код, состоящий из массивных, почти одинаковых строк кода с минимальными различиями, заставляет очень внимательно вчитываться, чтобы не упустить детали.

В свежих версиях python (>= 3.10) можно сделать так

```py
match num % 3, num % 5:
    case 0, 0:
        print('Число делится на 3 и на 5')
    case 0, _:
        print('Число делится на 3, но не делится на 5')
    case _, 0:
        print('Число не делится на 3, но делится на 5')
    case _:
        print('Число не делится ни на 3, ни на 5')
```

Этот вариант еще медленнее, но, на мой взгляд, в читабельности выигрывает.

Comment: +1 за ответ за новые знания, но в читабельности варианты с `_` да ещё с неведомым ранее в  Python` `case` выигрывают разве что для хорошо знающих язык:-)

Comment: @Сергей когда говорят про читабельность, обычно не имеют в виду читабельность для всех. Дискриминация новичков вполне оправдана, ведь новичок не перманентное состояния, а этап который все так или иначе переживут :)